# Java/JDBC/SQLite/BLOB - Major Flaw With Blob

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, blob

I am having a difficult time with just updating the data within my SQLite Database. I have tried using a `BinaryStream` however no luck. So I then decided, screw it. No need to update the Blob, if I delete any code related to the BLOB (even in the SQL Statement) the Update statement doesn't execute (properly). Prior to adding the BLOB everything worked fine. Now I just can't seem to understand why I cannot update my database any longer. If I take out the BLOB, program will say "Employee has successfully added to the database" however, when I look at my database, all information is the same. I can insert, search and delete them methods are fine, just updating just doesn't seem to be working for me. I am running out of ideas on what to do, could someone possibly help me? Even if it's not updating the BLOB, at this rate I'll take anything. Update or no update.

Code -

```
 updateEmployee.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Connection connection = null;
            PreparedStatement pst = null;

            try {

                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);

                String sql = "UPDATE employees SET ID =?, Name=?, Gender=?, DOB=?, Address=?, Postcode=?, NIN=?, JobTitle=?, StartDate=?, Salary=?, Email=?, Images=? WHERE ID=?";
                  pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

                pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(idTextField.getText()));
                pst.setString(2, nameTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(3, genderTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(4, dobTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(5, addressTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(6, postcodeTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(7, ninTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(8, jobtitleTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(9, startdateTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(10, salaryTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(11, emailTextField.getText());
                pst.setBytes(12, readFile(s));

                pst.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("EmployeeAdded");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee has successfully added to the database");             


                 connection.commit();
                pst.close();
                connection.close();
            }
            catch ( Exception e1 ) {


                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Uh oh! Something went wrong!");
                }
            }
        });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could print out the actual exception instead of something went wrong. That may give you and us an idea what has gone wrong.

Comment: @Shadow java.lang.NullPointerException  < That's the exception. The whole of it.

Comment: @Shadow Would I require the use of the ResultSet?

Comment: @Shadow Ok, I've managed to get past the java.lang.NullPointerException and a message box appears as when the statement is executed correctly. However, when looking at my Database, the information in the Database isn't updated or has changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java/JDBC/SQLite - Issue with Updating BLOB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266802/java-jdbc-sqlite-issue-with-updating-blob)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted the issue.

It was with the line-

```
 String sql = "UPDATE employees SET ID =?, Name=?, Gender=?, DOB=?, Address=?, Postcode=?, NIN=?, JobTitle=?, StartDate=?, Salary=?, Email=?, Images=? WHERE ID=?";
```

I needed to add `pst.setInt(12,Integer.parseInt(idTextField.getText()));` for `WHERE ID=?`.

Never happened to me before though, alas I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

Your command text has 13 parameter placeholders (`?`) but you are only defining 12 parameters. You are missing the last one, which should presumably be the same value as the first one ("ID").

Comment: Yes, sorted the problem. I posted the answer. Thanks for the comment.